# Setting Fontsize relative to base font size for various screen sizes

Tags: css, media-queries

I have base font size say 50px.

Based on screen size I want to set the size of various elements relative to base font size i.e. for device-width 320px the element h1 is 10% of base font and for device width 1024 px h1 is 20% of base font.

Can this be done in any way?

```
@media screen and (max-device-width : 320px)
{
  body or yourdiv element
  {
    font:10% of basefont;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-device-width : 1204px)
{
  body or yourdiv element
  {
    font:20% of basefont;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `rem`.This unit represents the font-size of the root element (e.g. the font-size of the `html` element), don't need too calculate (not so much :p) and be scared like with em [description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length)

```
html { font-size:50px; }
@media screen and (max-device-width : 320px)
{
    yourdiv element
    {
        font:0.1rem;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-device-width : 1204px)
{
    yourdiv element
    {
        font:0.2rem;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks..this is what I was looking for. I also want to know that can the base size be given in both px and percent? Specifying html{font-size: 67.5%} will be 10px on all on the browsers(mobile and desktop)?

Comment: Normally all new browsers seems to have 16px for 100% font-size so you can but for old browsers i'm not sure (or old mobile browsers too)

Answer (score 0):

You could use css calc(), to subtract the needed percentage from basefont size percentage.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc

Of course it is not supported in older browsers and older android browsers.

http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc